# Manipulate an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have an input parameter of type `IEnumerable`. It's not an `IList`. It's not an`ICollection<>.` Its a plain `IEnumerable`.

Furthermore I need to find an item and remove it from `IEnumerable`.

Something like this:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(item, data))
    {
       // something like this items.Remove(item); should happen here
    }
```

The problem is that `items` is of type `IEnumerable`. It doesn't have a remove method.

How do I remove an item? How to use items in foreach since foreach will throw an error when collection modified right?

Comment: that is not the only problem, you can't modify the collection inside of `foreach`

Comment: An `IEnumerable` (or `IEnumerable<T>`) is just plain not modifiable, regardless of whether you're using it in `foreach`. You can make a stronger requirement (require `ICollection`), or you can rework your logic to avoid the need for modification (create a new `IEnumerable`). Depending on which approach you take, the answers will be different.

Comment: @Selman22 Yes I mentioned that in my question. Please read my question again.

Comment: "Annoying plain" `IEnumerable`s as you say it, precisely cannot be *modified*. This is their very purpose and they are awesome this way. If you want to "remove" that item, create a new `IEnumerable` that doesn't contain it (using `.Except`), or delete it from the underlying container if you can access it.

Comment: Well its an interface therefore I could technically have 100 ifs and ask if the original type was a List or Collection or ObservableCollection or HashSet or whatever possible. I would like to avoid those if statements.

Comment: Or you could just walk to whoever decided to have this requirement that you should be removing items from an IEnumerable, and club him/her over the head until he/she realizes that this is not a good design.

Comment: I cant. Its a third party dll. I wish I could. :) :) :)

Comment: Please, by all means tell us what third party product is so brain dead as to have this requirement. That way we can all boycott it.

Comment: No point in discussion what third party did this. The solution must be  found and I was hoping you could give me some suggestions guys. Else I am stuck with having tons of if statements asking if the user might have passed a List<> or Collection<> or BindingList<> or whatever. All those types implement IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a new enumeration, one short implementation could be (using LINQ):

```
public IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumeration, T toRemove)
{
    return enumeration.Except(new[] { toRemove });
}
```

And use it like:

```
annoyingEnumeration = this.Remove(annoyingEnumeration, annoyingItem);
```

For non-generic Enumerations

```
public IEnumerable Remove(IEnumerable enumeration, object toRemove)
{
    foreach (var e in enumeration)
    {
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(e, toRemove))
        {
            yield return e;
        }
    }
}
```

And to have the second one as a new `Except`-Linq-style operation on the `IEnumerable` interface, you might define something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public IEnumerable Without(this IEnumerable enumeration, object toLeaveOut)
    {
        foreach (var e in enumeration)
        {
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(e, toLeaveOut))
            {
                yield return e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
annoyingEnumeration = annyingEnumeration.Without(annoyingItem);
```

**EDIT**

> *use 100 ifs to check for the real type*

Sounds like a bad idea as the caller can give you an own IEnumerable implementation and you can't do anything against it. When I'm only exposing an IEnumerable interface I will not allow the consuments to modify the enumeration, otherwise I'd expose an ICollection or IList.

Comment: I have an IEnumerable not an IEnumerable<>. Can you provide me a solution with IEnumerable only.

Comment: No new collection may be created, the old must stay and the istance must be the same.

Comment: Then it is easy: no :)

Comment: Well its an interface therefore I could technically have 100 ifs and ask if the original type was a List or Collection or ObservableCollection or HashSet or whatever possible. I would like to avoid those if statements. That would be the only way I see right now. I was hoping you guys could give me some better advices.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have stated that creating a new object is not acceptable, and you can make no stronger constraints about the object than it implementing `IEnumerable`, then the problem is provably not solvable.  It's *possible* that the underlying implementation of the type is mutable in some way, and that you could mutate it to remove the item, but it's equally possible that it is not.  Even if it were, it would be *extraordinarily* bad practice to be reaching into the underlying data of an `IEnumerable` to mutate it, even if it would be possible.

Instead, despite your refusal to accept it, you almost certainly need to, as well as ought to, create a new object to represent all of the items that you want to keep; either that, or provide some stronger constraint as to what type you are dealing with, so that you will know both that its mutable, and how to mutate it.

Comment: Upvoted because given the comments from the original poster, this is the only real sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the collection inside a loop, I would convert it to a List and manipulate the list, for sample:

```
var custom = new ArrayList();    

foreach(var item in items)
{
    // invert the check
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item, data))
    {
       // add on the custom result
       custom.Add(item);
    }
}

return custom;
```

Comment: Look my edits, you could work using the `ArrayList` object and change your condition to keep it on the collection.

Comment: No new instance may be created. The remove change must be executed on the same instance.

Comment: You are out of luck @devhedgehog ... An IEnumerable cannot be modified. Simple as that.

Comment: Well its an interface therefore I could technically have 100 ifs and ask if the original type was a List or Collection or ObservableCollection or HashSet or whatever possible. I would like to avoid those if statements.

Comment: @devhedgehog That's assuming the underlying collection is some known mutable type.  It's entirely possible that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new collection, based on original collection.

```
var result = new List<object>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item, data))
    {
       result.Add(item);
    }
}
```

or

```
var filtered = items.Where(i => !object.ReferenceEquals(i, data));
```

Comment: No new collection allowed. The instance must stay the same.

Comment: @devhedgehog: So, you can't change original collection, using only IEnumerable<T> interface. In any way it will be a new collection.

Comment: It will not. IEnumerable is an interface. I could technically cast it to List if the user passed a list as parameter and then I would be able to execute remove method on same instance.

Comment: @devhedgehog .. You cannot modify an IEnumerable without creating a new instance... listen to what EVERYONE is telling you.

Comment: Well its an interface therefore I could technically have 100 ifs and ask if the original type was a List or Collection or ObservableCollection or HashSet or whatever possible. All those types implement IEnumerable. I would like to avoid those if statements. That would be the only way I see right now. I was hoping you guys could give me some better advices.

Comment: @devhedgehog: Technically you can downcast IEnumerable to IList or List (or enything else) but it will be realy bad solution. You can also use dynamic invoke, reflection api, unmanaged code etc. but it will be bad practise.
Problems in you design should not be solved with workarounds.

Comment: I know and that is also the reason why I am asking you guys to share your experience on this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following extension method to remove an item. It returns new `IEnumerable`, containing all items from the original collection, except the specified item:

```
public static System.Collections.IEnumerable Remove<T>(this System.Collections.IEnumerable collection, T data)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item, data))
            yield return item;
}
```

Usage:

```
collection = collection.Remove(data);
```